# Pipes and file descriptors within bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, script, pipe

Streaming PI camera video to VLC using the following command from bash prompt works OK:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 12 | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8081/}' :demux=h264 --h264-fps=12
```

But when I put the command above in a script e.g. `rtsp-stream.sh` I get no errors but VLC seems to be receiving an empty stream (script has `#!/bin/bash` header).

I feel it is the pipe that causes the issue, but cannot find a way around it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: I run the script from the bash prompt: `./rtsp-stream.sh`

Comment: Please add this to your script and add its output to your question (no comment here): `type raspivid cvlc; echo "$PATH"`

Comment: ```raspivid is /usr/bin/raspivid

cvlc is /usr/bin/cvlc

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin```